# Can I create a stock recovery from Nandroid backup or from OTA? How?

Tags: ota-update, nandroid

I am looking for a stock recovery for my phone (HTC One M7, rooted, s-on,CID: HTC__102, Software number: 4.19.401.11). But I cannot find it. The reason I want this recovery is that I want to experiment if it is possible to keep my phone rooted but going back to Stock recovery so that I can get OTA updates.

I have a nandroid back up of my stock ROM (I created it in TWRP, so it is after flashing the TWRP recovery),  and also I have downloaded an OTA for my phone from forums.

Is it possible I can get an stock recovery image from OTA zip file or Nandroid backup?

Thanks.

Comment: If your phone is rooted, it means some parts of `/system` partition were modified. An OTA update will most likely fail to install, regardless if you have stock or custom recovery.

Comment: I flashed stock recovery. now the Update process starts, it reboots the phone, and a progress bar fills up. when the progress bar finishes it reboots the phone. but i guess flashing stock recovery was not done properly, so it cannot finalize the update process and when the phone finally starts the update has not taken place.

Comment: It's probably not the recovery that's preventing the OTA from properly installing, but the fact that your phone is rooted.  Can you try un-rooting it (do a search for instructions for your root method) and applying the OTA again?

Comment: ok Chahk, let me try that. Just a question: I am assuming that unrooting will earas all my data, right? is there a way I can backup my apps and data and restore it after unrooting?

Comment: Un-rooting itself will probably not erase your data, although that depends on the rooting method you used in the first place. As far as backing up apps and data, take a look at Android's built-in [`adb backup`](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-phone-backup-unlock-root-t1420351) tool. It works on non-rooted devices as well, so you should be able to do a restore after installing OTA update.